# Configuration of parameter sonar.java.libraries when launched from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

My Jenkins job uses the Sonarqube plugin to start an analysis. It is reported that `sonar.java.libraries` is not set and the result may be inaccurate.

What value should I assign to this variable? The project is built with a maven build step. So all the dependecies are somewhere on the jenkins node under `/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/`.

Is `sonar.java.libraries = /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/**` really a correct value or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using all files in your maven repository should work but it might make the analysis slower as the plugin will have to look for classes in high number of jars.

**You should use the SonarQube scanner for maven**. It will automatically pick up the classpath from your maven configuration.